# Django equivalent of COUNT with GROUP BY

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I know Django 1.1 has some new aggregation methods. However I couldn't figure out equivalent of the following query:

```
SELECT player_type, COUNT(*) FROM players GROUP BY player_type;
```

Is it possible with Django 1.1's Model Query API or should I just use plain SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: how to do SELECT COUNT(\*) GROUP BY and ORDER BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101665/django-how-to-do-select-count-group-by-and-order-by)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you are using Django 1.1 beta (trunk):

```
Player.objects.values('player_type').order_by().annotate(Count('player_type'))
```

- `values('player_type')` - for inclusion only `player_type` field into `GROUP BY` clause.
- `order_by()` - for exclusion possible default ordering that can cause not needed fields inclusion in `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 16):

Django 1.1 does support aggregation methods like count. You can find [the full documentation here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

To answer your question, you can use something along the lines of:

```
from django.db.models import Count
q = Player.objects.annotate(Count('games'))
print q[0]
print q[0].games__count
```

This will need slight tweaking depending on your actual model.

Edit: The above snippet generates aggregations on a per-object basis. If you want aggregation on a particular field in the model, you can use the `values` method:

```
from django.db.models import Count
q = Player.objects.values('playertype').annotate(Count('games')).order_by()
print q[0]
print q[0].games__count
```

`order_by()` is needed because fields that are in the default ordering are automatically selected even if they are not explicitly passed to `values()`. This call to `order_by()` clears any ordering and makes the query behave as expected.

Also, if you want to count the field that is used for grouping (equivalent to `COUNT(*)`), you can use:

```
from django.db.models import Count
q = Player.objects.values('playertype').annotate(Count('playertype')).order_by()
print q[0]
print q[0].playertype__count
```

Comment: This call will produce wrong `GROUP BY` clause - with all model fields included. But author asked only one field grouping.

Comment: I was trying to give a general example and point to the documentation. This is why I said that my snippet needed tweaking. I've added more examples to my answer now. Thanks for the comment. :)