# Django: GROUP BY two values

Tags: django

I would basically like to do [the same as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842031/django-equivalent-of-count-with-group-by), but grouping by combinations of two values, rather than just one:

```
SELECT player_type, team, COUNT(*)
FROM players
GROUP BY player_type, team;
```

Does anyone know whether, and how, this is possible in Django? I'm using 1.2.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
(Player.objects
 .values('player_type', 'team')
 .order_by()
 .annotate(Count('player_type'), Count('team'))
```

Comment: This answer would actually return a query with two calls to COUNT, both player_type and team. As Django does not support the asterisk parameter for the count, COUNT(*) can be achieved by using a non-null field. The PK is a good candidate for this. thus using Count('pk') would be the right answer...

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to do this is to count the `id` field of the objects and trigger `values()` and `annotate()` into doing the grouping.

Assuming the OP's original query, with a Django (v4.2) datamodel something like this:

```py
# home/models.py
class Player(models.Model):
    player_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    team = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Executing:

```py
Player.objects.values('player_type', 'team').annotate(Count('id'))
```

Will produce the desired output, with the counts in a new field `id__count`.

It's a good idea to sanity-check the `.query` property on the **QuerySet**.  In the previous example, something similar to this is generated:

```sql
-- print(Player.objects.values('player_type', 'team').annotate(Count('id')).query)

SELECT "home_player"."player_type"
     , "home_player"."team"
     , COUNT("home_player"."id") AS "id__count"
FROM "home_player"
GROUP BY "home_player"."player_type", "home_player"."team"
```