# Django ORM Count by multiple fields

Tags: django

I'm working with Django and I need to group a model by multiple fields.

The query I want is:

```
select field1, field2 from tbl group by field1, field2 having count(*) > 1
```

Then what I've tried is the following:

```
Tbl.objects.annotate(cnt=Count('field1','field2')).filter(cnt__gt=1)
```

But, it didn't work.
Can't group by multiple fields on ORM?
Do I need to write RawQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your django queryset, you have to first use the .values() to select which columns you wish to group by on.

```
Tbl.objects.values('field1', 'field2').annotate(cnt=Count('pk')).filter(cnt__gt=1)
# or whatever you needed to do
```

**EDIT**

Also, please check previous questions before asking.

[Django orm group by multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483884/django-orm-group-by-multiple-columns)

[Django: GROUP BY two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916621/django-group-by-two-values?lq=1)