# django most efficient way to count same field values in a query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Lets say if I have a model that has lots of fields, but I only care about a charfield. Lets say that charfield can be anything so I don't know the possible values, but I know that the values frequently overlap. So I could have 20 objects with "abc" and 10 objects with "xyz" or I could have 50 objects with "def" and 80 with "stu" and i have 40000 with no overlap which I really don't care about.

How do I count the objects efficiently? What I would like returned is something like:

{'abc': 20, 'xyz':10, 'other': 10,000}

or something like that, w/o making a ton of SQL calls.

### EDIT:

I dont know if anyone will see this since I am editing it kind of late, but...

I have this model:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    purl = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

and from the answers, I have done this:

```
groups = Action.objects.filter(author='James').values('purl').annotate(count=Count('purl'))
```

but...

this is what groups is:

```
{"purl": "waka"},{"purl": "waka"},{"purl": "waka"},{"purl": "waka"},{"purl": "mora"},{"purl": "mora"},{"purl": "mora"},{"purl": "mora"},{"purl": "mora"},{"purl": "lora"}
```

(I just filled purl with dummy values)

what I want is

```
{'waka': 4, 'mora': 5, 'lora': 1}
```

Hopefully someone will see this edit...

### EDIT 2:

Apparently **my database** (BigTable) **does not support the aggregate functions** of Django and this is why I have been having all the problems.

Answer (score 113):

You want something similar to "count ... group by". You can do this with the aggregation features of django's ORM:

```
from django.db.models import Count

fieldname = 'myCharField'
MyModel.objects.values(fieldname)
    .order_by(fieldname)
    .annotate(the_count=Count(fieldname))
```

Previous questions on this subject:

- [How to query as GROUP BY in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629551/how-to-query-as-group-by-in-django)
- [Django equivalent of COUNT with GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842031/django-equivalent-of-count-with-group-by)

Comment: actually, I had this:

groups =Action.objects.filter(author=
           author).values('purl').annotate(count=Count('purl'))

a = [each for each in groups]

but a is just equal to just a bunch of these: {"purl": "wakawaka"}

with no count key for the dict.

Comment: I've edited the answer to account for this, but just in case it doesn't get approved: if you are receiving multiple results which don't look aggregated: ensure you are ordering the queryset by the field you wish to group by.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is the ONLY answer that mentioned order_by before annotating, which is REQUIRED to work.

Comment: Why is `order_by` required?

Comment: @Jarad the "previous questions" linked mention it, as does [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-order-by) of the docs: "Fields that are mentioned in the `order_by()` part of a queryset are used when selecting the output data, even if they are not otherwise specified in the `values()` call. These extra fields are used to group “like” results together and they can make otherwise identical result rows appear to be separate. This shows up, particularly, when counting things." So default ordering could add extraneous fields that mess things up

Answer (score 23):

This is called aggregation, and Django [supports it directly](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/).

You can get your exact output by filtering the values you want to count, getting the list of values, and counting them, all in one set of database calls:

```
from django.db.models import Count
MyModel.objects.filter(myfield__in=('abc', 'xyz')).\
        values('myfield').annotate(Count('myfield'))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use Django's `Count` [aggregation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) on a queryset to accomplish this. Something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
queryset = MyModel.objects.all().annotate(count = Count('my_charfield'))
for each in queryset:
    print "%s: %s" % (each.my_charfield, each.count)
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless your field value is always guaranteed to be in a specific case, it may be useful to transform it prior to performing a count, i.e. so 'apple' and 'Apple' would be treated as the same.

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

MyModel.objects.annotate(lower_title=Lower('title')).values('lower_title').annotate(num=Count('lower_title')).order_by('num')
```