# Count same field values in Django queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-database

I have a Django model with three fields: `product`, `condition` and `quantity` with data such as:

```
| Product | Condition | Quantity |
+---------+-----------+----------+
| A       | new       | 2        |
| A       | new       | 3        |
| A       | new       | 4        |
| A       | old       | 1        |
| A       | old       | 2        |
| B       | new       | 2        |
| B       | new       | 3        |
| B       | new       | 1        |
| B       | old       | 4        |
| B       | old       | 2        |
```

I'd like to sum the quantities of the entries where `product` and `condition` are equal:

```
| Product | Condition | Quantity |
+---------+-----------+----------+
| A       | new       | 9        |
| A       | old       | 3        |
| B       | new       | 6        |
| B       | old       | 6        |
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606416/django-most-efficient-way-to-count-same-field-values-in-a-query/3606466) helps to count entries with the same field value, but I need to count two fields.

How could I implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Model.objects.values('product', 'condition').order_by().annotate(Sum('quantity'))
```