# Is there any way to get total count of table row and table data in single Query

Tags: python, django, django-orm

The problem is, to get count and table data, I have to hit the database two times in Django. For example:

```
count = queryset.count() # To get count
data = queryset.values('columns') # To get data
```

Is there any way to get data in the single query. One solution is to use len() function, but it is not good for a bigger table to load in RAM.

In mysql, I got this, But how to execute through Django ORM

```
SELECT t1.count, id FROM table1, (select count(*) as count FROM table1) as t1 limit 10;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django most efficient way to count same field values in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606416/django-most-efficient-way-to-count-same-field-values-in-a-query)

Answer (score 0):

I mean `len` should just count what is already in memory if you get the data first, so it should be better than two queries to database.

```
data = queryset.values('columns') # To get data
count = len(data) # To get count from database records in memory
```

Anyway, for direct database queries without the model layer from Django docs:

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT t1.count, id FROM table1, (select count(*) as count FROM table1) as t1 limit 10")
        row = dictfetchall(cursor)

    return row
```

Comment: yes, @stree len() had solved my problem, but It will load all database records in memory which is an issue for a bigger table.