# How do I find the name and its count for a FK object?

Tags: django, django-orm

Having these models:

```
class AccidentJob(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Accident(TimeStampedModel, models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(AccidentJob, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want something like this:

```
[
    {'job__name': 'Auxiliar de surtido', 'count': 2},
    {'job__name': 'Técnico de mantenimiento', 'count': 1}
]
```

but I am getting this:

```
[
    {'job__name': 'Auxiliar de surtido', 'count': 1},
    {'job__name': 'Auxiliar de surtido', 'count': 1},
    {'job__name': 'Técnico de mantenimiento', 'count': 1}
]
```

This is my query:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Accident.objects.values(
    "job__name"
).annotate(
    count=Count('job__name')
).values("job__name", "count")
```

I can do it with Python, but I would prefer having PostgreSQL do the work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3606466/3007120), looks like it just need an `order_by`

```py
Accident.objects.values(
    "job__name"
).annotate(
    count=Count('job__name')
).values(
    "job__name", "count"
).order_by(
    "job__name"
)
```

So after tweaks, this is a better version:

```py
Accident.objects.values(
    "job__name"
).order_by(
    "job__name"
).annotate(
    count=Count('job__name')
)
```