# Django: remove duplicates from order by -count query

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

**I want to have a list with the most picked Player objects, descending.**

I have the following table structure:

<kbd>id</kbd><kbd>player_id</kbd><kbd>formation_id</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>1</kbd>                  
<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>2</kbd>                  
<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>             <kbd>3</kbd>                  
<kbd>4</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>             <kbd>1</kbd>

This is my FormationPlayer model:

```
class FormationPlayer(models.Model):
    formation = models.ForeignKey(Formation, related_name='players', db_index=True)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='+', db_index=True)
```

I have the following query which returns FormationPlayer objects, ordered on most number of picks (occurencies) descending:

```
FormationPlayer.objects.annotate(num_picked=Count('player_id')).order_by('-num_picked').select_related('player')
```

However this also returns duplicates, I already tried to add distinct() at the end, also tried distinct after the annotate but that didn't change a thing.

What I want to accomplish is a list of the most picked players. The most picked players are the players whose player id is the most occurring in the FormationPlayer table.

Answer (score 2):

You need GROUP BY expression generated by Django, as described in this question:

[How to do SELECT COUNT(*) GROUP BY and ORDER BY in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101665/django-how-to-do-select-count-group-by-and-order-by)

so your line of code will be something similar to

```
from django.db.models import Count
FormationPlayer.objects.all().values('player_id').annotate(total=Count('player_id')).order_by('total')
```

Comment: this works, only I need to do a select related on it too. How would I do that?

Comment: not sure what you want to get in the end, describe it please