# How to count occurences in list with template filters in django and pass them to the template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-template-filters

I have a django app in which I am counting the clicked urls. I am saving the clicked urls in a list in my view. Now I want to iterate through the list and count each occurence (of the urls). Then I want to show each url with the counted number in the template. What I am doing so far looks like this:

My view:

```
class AnalyticsIndexView(StaffRequiredMixin, ListView):
  template_name = 'analytics_list.html'
  model = UrlTime

  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(AnalyticsIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['url_views_list'] = UrlTime.objects.all()
    context['total_views'] = UrlTime.objects.all().count

    context['home_view'] = UrlTime.objects.filter(associated_url='/').count()
    context['job_list'] = UrlTime.objects.filter(associated_url='/jobs/').count()
    context['job_detail'] = UrlTime.objects.filter(associated_url='/jobs/{How to pass id??}').count()
    context['job_'] = UrlTime.objects.filter(associated_url='/jobs/{???id?????}').count()

    return context
```

Now that works. But I don't want to hardcode the links obviously, also because I don't know which urls will be in it. (that handles my custom middleware). I would like to capture each url in the list, count it, and show link and linkcount in the template. I already tried with Collections but it didn't work as I wanted it. Also with the harcoding I don't know how to do that with links that have a dynamic id....

Anyone has any suggestions? Help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a [GroupBy and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19102493/10310124) aggregation. Try overriding `get_query_set` method with the following query:

```
def get_queryset():
    return UrlTime.objects.values('associated_url').annotate(
        url_count=Count('associated_url')
    )
```

Comment: that's fantastic, thank you so much!! I get this back: <QuerySet [{'associated_url': '/jobs/', 'url_count': 1}, {'associated_url': '/', 'url_count': 8}, {'associated_url': '/analytics', 'url_count': 1}, {'associated_url': '/jobs/1/', 'url_count': 4}, {'associated_url': '/jobs', 'url_count': 7}]>

Comment: with a triple loop I managed to turn it into: associated_url /jobs/ url_count 1 associated_url / url_count 8 associated_url /analytics url_count 1 associated_url /jobs/1/ url_count 4 associated_url /jobs url_count 7. I only need to seperate somehow this data. Your solution is great.

Comment: of course I can do now 
            {% for keys in home_view %}
              {{ keys.associated_url }}
              {{ keys.url_count }}
            {% endfor %}