# Cannot filter my Django model depence on created_date

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am trying to do a chart. My database has created_date. I am getting product data every day about 150 times and I want to see a daily increase and decrease of my data. I have no problem with my front end and Django-template (I try manual data and it works well) I just want to see the last 7 days chart.

When I use `Products.objects.filter(created_dates=days)` filter method I am getting empty Queryset.

I already try `created_dates__gte=startdate,created_dates__lte=enddate` it return empty Queryset to.

I also try `created_dates__range` to there is no answer too.

I just get data from `created_dates__gte=days` but I don't want these data.

***view.py***

```
from datetime import date,timedelta

import datetime

def data_chart(request):
   data = []
   week_days = [datetime.datetime.now().date()-timedelta(days=i) for i in range (1,7)]
   for days in week_days:
      product_num = Products.objects.filter(created_dates=days)
      date =days.strftime("%d.%m")
      item = {"day": date,"value":len(product_num)}
      data.append(item)
   return render(request, 'chartpage.html', {'data': data})
```

In my database, I have thousands of data and my daily data about 150. My created_dates column format like this.

***created_dates col:***
 `2020-10-19 09:39:19.894184`

So what is wrong with my code?. Could you please help?

Comment: Show your model as well. Is `created_dates` a DateTimeField?

Comment: MY model like this     created_dates = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,verbose_name = ("Oluşturma Tarihi"),null=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a single aggregation query:

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Count


def data_chart(request):
    cutoff = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    raw_data = (
        Products.objects.filter(created_dates__gte=cutoff)
        .values_list("created_dates__date")
        .annotate(count=Count("id"))
        .values_list("created_dates__date", "count")
    )
    data = [{"day": str(date), "value": value} for (date, value) in raw_data]
    return render(request, "chartpage.html", {"data": data})
```

Comment: I will try and let you know end of the day

Comment: I don't know how but it works well. The chart prepared well. But you write the date and count wrong. It supposed to be "day": str(day), "value": value, and because it returns as datetime class I use str(day). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MuratDemir Ah, yeah. Fixed the typo :)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to compare DateTimeField type (created_dates) with Date type (week_days is list of days) so maybe You should try __date lookup.

```
product_num = Products.objects.filter(created_dates__date=days)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#date

Furthermore maybe You should consider start using Count() database function with group by instead of iterating over days.

Here is great explanation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19102493/5160341

Comment: return like this again <QuerySet []> so no solution yet