# Django Query to get count of all distinct values for particular column

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-postgresql

I am trying to fetch count of all distinct values in particular column
for example I have following table in model name MyModel :

```
Id  City     vendor

1   Mumbai      2
2   Pune        3
3   Mumbai      1
4   Yavatmal    2
5   Pune        5
```

I am looking for output something like this:

```
[{'Mumbai':2},{'Pune':2},{'Yavatmal':1}]
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like the comment of **solarissmoke** above. In that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842031/django-equivalent-of-count-with-group-by) you can see the solution:

```
from django.db.models import Count
MyModel.objects.values('city').annotate(the_count=Count('city'))
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work properly, you need to also use `order_by`, as done answer in the duplicate. Without it `the count` is just equal to `1` for everything.